# From a module with errors, import valid entities

Tags: python

I have a module A.py, that holds some constants, and a class. The class is not ready yet, so meny of it's functions implementations are `NOT IMPLEMENTED YET` - that is, I want if anyone calls this function, python to fail with syntactic error.

However, now I am doing `from A import constants` and python is failing with the error within the function within the class.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can only import functions from another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pass` to your methods:

```
class SomeClass(object):
   def some_method(self):
       pass
   def method(self):
       pass
```

This way, you will not have issues importing the class.

The other option is to raise [`NotImplementedError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NotImplementedError).

As importing will evaluate the module, you need to have error free code in your file.

Comment: Thanks. "You can accept an answer within 6 minutes". Could you please either explain or link to a resource, why is the whole module evaluated. What does "evaluated" meann at all in an interpreted language?

Comment: Try [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) in the documentation on more on what happens during importing.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than leaving in the syntax errors, explicitly `raise NotImplementedError` from your unfinished function. Or move the constants to a separate module.

Comment: Thanks (+1)! Accepting the other answer, because it linked to documentation and is marginally more easy on me.